# Is there a way to set width of SVG element to 100%?

Tags: css, svg

Does SVG support percent widths? I've tried setting the width to 100% and it does not change. If not is there anything I can do to make sure a horizontal line stretches all the way across an element?

I have two use cases:

1. SVG Horizontal Line starts at 20px from left and extends 100% to edge of parent div. The div is flexible so it's size changes. So line would have to grow or shrink to look right.
2. SVG Vertical Line starts at y 0 and stretches the height of the container it's in. Container height is flexible and may grow or shrink.

Horizontal line going across. This does not seem to work in the code snippet editor for me here but this shows a line on my webpage. Maybe I'm missing something:

```html
<div style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px;width:150px;height:150px;border:1px dashed blue">
  <svg>
    <line x1="0" x2="100" y1="0" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1;"></line>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: The important thing is that your SVG needs to have a `viewBox`.

Answer (score 2):

This works just fine, hover the `div` to see in action:

```css
div {
  border:1px solid;
  background:#f8f8f8;
  width:25vw;
  height:25vh;
  transition:all 0.3s;
}
div:hover {
  width:75vw;
  height:75vh;
}
svg {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewbox="0 0 260 220">
    <polygon points="200,10 250,190 10,210" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I was sure I read that percentage sizing doesn't work with SVG. This is great news.